# How to accsess parent class with jQuery/Coffeescript

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

Situation:

I Have a class named DrawLogic this looks like (in coffeescript):

```
 class DrawLogic
    mark: => 
        do something
    etc ....

 @DrawLogic = new DrawLogic
```

later in HTML Page i create "dynmical constans" i.e. names coming from server programm i want to use/type/have only once

```
<script>
DrawLogic.NameSpaceName='orion42'; 
.... 
</script>
```

so far so fine, and working

Now to extend jQuery for my (svg) element (inside my class DrawLogic)

```
class DrawLogic 
   ....
   init: ->
      jQuery.fn.td_data = (attr_name) ->  #look at the '->'
          do something with 'this' 
           #the element of selector works fine     
           #to use the "DrawLogic.NameSpaceName" pseudo constant
           #i have to write:

          window.DrawLogic.NameSpaceName #was orion42 before

   etc...
```

but *i am within my "DrawLogic class"*, if i would use '=>' i where within the class scope and the this or (@) where fine for `this.NameSpaceName` (instead of `window.DrawLogic.NameSpaceName`), but i loose the "element" of the selector.

so how? is there a better solution for referencing the class I am inside than using "window.DrawLogic.NameSpaceName"? I dont want to repeat my self ...

To say it clear, I need to type "DrawLogic" only 4 times (3 in coffescript and once in HTML, but now i have to use it with each reference in jQuery extendet function :-(

is there a better solution?

Comment: yes, typo, i correct this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not exactly right when you say that you're inside `DrawLogic` inside here:

```
class DrawLogic 
    init: ->
        jQuery.fn.td_data = (attr_name) ->
            # Here you're not really inside DrawLogic anymore.
```

Inside `td_data` you're really inside whatever the caller says you're inside, this is standard JavaScript behavior. The above is equivalent to:

```
f = (attr_name) -> #...
class DrawLogic
    init: -> jQuery.fn.td_data = f
```

unless you have local variables inside `init` that `td_data` uses.

If `window.DrawLogic.NameSpaceName` is too much then you should be able to use `DrawLogic.NameSpaceName` or use a closure:

```
class DrawLogic
    init: ->
        DL = @constructor
        jQuery.fn.td_data = (attr_name) ->
            # Use DL.NameSpaceName in here
```